# set_partitions into numba nopython environment

Tags: python, numba, partition

I need to paerallelize some operations executed on all the partitions of a set.
So, I need to call the `set_partitions` function (included in `more-itertools` package) into a numba nopython environment.
Find below the actual function definition.

```
def set_partitions(iterable, k=None):
"""
Yield the set partitions of *iterable* into *k* parts. Set partitions are
not order-preserving.

>>> iterable = 'abc'
>>> for part in set_partitions(iterable, 2):
...     print([''.join(p) for p in part])
['a', 'bc']
['ab', 'c']
['b', 'ac']


If *k* is not given, every set partition is generated.

>>> iterable = 'abc'
>>> for part in set_partitions(iterable):
...     print([''.join(p) for p in part])
['abc']
['a', 'bc']
['ab', 'c']
['b', 'ac']
['a', 'b', 'c']

"""
L = list(iterable)
n = len(L)
if k is not None:
    if k < 1:
        raise ValueError(
            "Can't partition in a negative or zero number of groups"
        )
    elif k > n:
        return

def set_partitions_helper(L, k):
    n = len(L)
    if k == 1:
        yield [L]
    elif n == k:
        yield [[s] for s in L]
    else:
        e, *M = L
        for p in set_partitions_helper(M, k - 1):
            yield [[e], *p]
        for p in set_partitions_helper(M, k):
            for i in range(len(p)):
                yield p[:i] + [[e] + p[i]] + p[i + 1 :]

if k is None:
    for k in range(1, n + 1):
        yield from set_partitions_helper(L, k)
else:
    yield from set_partitions_helper(L, k)
```

I know numba could have troubles using lists of lists, so it can be sufficient for me that the function does not operate directly on the iterable.
I mean I can accept the following declaration of the function.

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def numba_set_partitions(n, k=None):
```

The output will be a typed list containing ndarrays which in turn contain the indices of the original set to be partitioned (simarly having `iterable = range(n)`).

If that would not be feasible (maybe due to the dynamic dimensions of the ndarrays in the list) the output could be a ndarray of integers with length `n`. The integers will be the labels of the subsets in partition; in particular, if the current partition contains N subsets the integers will range between 0 and N-1.

I hope I was clear enough.

Thanks for help!

Ivan

[EDIT]

I think I am close to the solution...

I rewritten the function in a less pythonic way; find it below.

```
def numba_set_partitions_helper(n, k):
    if k == 1:
        yield np.zeros(n, dtype=np.int_)
    elif n == k:
        yield np.arange(n, dtype=np.int_)
    else:
        for p in numba_set_partitions_helper(n - 1, k - 1):
            yield np.append(0, p + 1)
        for p in numba_set_partitions_helper(n - 1, k):
            for i in range(max(p) + 1):
                yield np.append(i, p)

def numba_set_partitions(n, k = None):
    if k is not None:
        if k < 1:
            raise ValueError(
                "Can't partition in a negative or zero number of groups"
            )
        elif k > n:
            return
                
    if k is None:
        for k in range(1, n + 1):
            for indices in numba_set_partitions_helper(n, k):
                yield indices
    else:
        for indices in numba_set_partitions_helper(n, k):
            yield indices
```

In particular:

- I avoided lists using arrays of indices;
- I avoided nested function definition;
- I avoided `yield from` by using for loop on the iterator.

The numba compilation still doesn't work.
I obtain the following error.

```
TypingError: No implementation of function Function(<built-in function lt>) found for signature:
 
lt(none, Literal[int](1))
 
There are 22 candidate implementations:
      - Of which 18 did not match due to:
      Overload of function 'lt': File: <numerous>: Line N/A.
        With argument(s): '(none, int64)':
       No match.
      - Of which 2 did not match due to:
      Operator Overload in function 'lt': File: unknown: Line unknown.
        With argument(s): '(none, int64)':
       No match for registered cases:
        * (bool, bool) -> bool
        * (int8, int8) -> bool
        * (int16, int16) -> bool
        * (int32, int32) -> bool
        * (int64, int64) -> bool
        * (uint8, uint8) -> bool
        * (uint16, uint16) -> bool
        * (uint32, uint32) -> bool
        * (uint64, uint64) -> bool
        * (float32, float32) -> bool
        * (float64, float64) -> bool
      - Of which 1 did not match due to:
      Overload in function 'set_lt': File: numba/cpython/setobj.py: Line 1680.
        With argument(s): '(none, int64)':
       Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
         TypingError: All arguments must be Sets, got (none, int64)
  raised from /Users/krono/mambaforge/envs/apple/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/cpython/setobj.py:108
      - Of which 1 did not match due to:
      Overload in function 'set_lt': File: numba/cpython/setobj.py: Line 1680.
        With argument(s): '(none, Literal[int](1))':
       Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
         TypingError: All arguments must be Sets, got (none, Literal[int](1))
  raised from /Users/krono/mambaforge/envs/apple/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/cpython/setobj.py:108
```

Do you have aby idea how can I solve this issue?

[EDIT 2]

If I decorate only the function `numba_set_partitions_helper` I obtain the following error.

```
TypingError: Invalid use of getiter with parameters (none)

During: typing of intrinsic-call at /Users/krono/Desktop/test.py (13)
```